# Serializing Event data for multiple Contacts using contactEvents method

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, contact, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

I'm using the Fuel REST API [contactEvents](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/contacts/contactEvents.html) method to serialize Event data into an Event Data Extension. The following request works:

```
{
    "contactKey": "susan@sausage.com",
    "eventDefinitionKey": "CONTACT-EVENT-59b53fce-d732-3509-7b12-dc537f8565c3",
    "data": [{
        "key": "MemberPreferences",
        "name": "Member Preferences",
        "id": "84CFE1C6-0345-461E-BF12-1BF346B8407C",
        "items": [{
            "values": [{
                "name": "Preference",
                "value": "frankfurter"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Now I note that according to the documentation, I can also omit the `contactKey` name/value pair from the parent object tree of the request payload and include it as an item in the Event data object (as a `ContactKey` attribute was added to the Event Data Extension when it was created) as per the following request:

```
{
    "eventDefinitionKey": "CONTACT-EVENT-59b53fce-d732-3509-7b12-dc537f8565c3",
    "data": [{
        "key": "MemberPreferences",
        "name": "Member Preferences",
        "id": "84CFE1C6-0345-461E-BF12-1BF346B8407C",
        "items": [{
            "values": [
                  {
                     "name":"ContactKey",
                     "value":"susan@sausage.com"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"Preference",
                     "value":"frankfurter"
                  }
               ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

This works too. That is, the Event data is serialized into my Events Data Extension and the Contact enters the Interaction.

What I would like to do is to include Event data for multiple Contacts in a single request. That is, if customers sign up for an offer, then rather making individual requests for each Contact (which could be problematic as there is a a soft capped limit of 50,000 requests per day that an app can make), I want to include multiple Contacts in the `items` array of my request as follows:

```
{
   "eventDefinitionKey":"CONTACT-EVENT-59b53fce-d732-3509-7b12-dc537f8565c3",
   "data":[
      {
         "key":"MemberPreferences",
         "name":"Member Preferences",
         "id":"84CFE1C6-0345-461E-BF12-1BF346B8407C",
         "items":[
            {
               "values":[
                  {
                     "name":"ContactKey",
                     "value":"susan@sausage.com"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"Preference",
                     "value":"frankfurter"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "values":[
                  {
                     "name":"ContactKey",
                     "value":"simon@sausage.com"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"Preference",
                     "value":"bratwurst"
                  }
               ]
            }]
      }]
}
```

This request returns a successful response, but no records are serialized into the Event Data Extension. Am I doing something wrong here, or isn't this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one Contact at a time can currently be sent in per ContactEvent request with the API.

In your payload, you include the Attribute Set `key`, `name`, and `id`.  You only need to send in one of these 3 values.  Key and Id are the safest to send since names can be localized.  Since you know all 3 values I would recommend `id` first, but `key` would simplify debugging. Always use the `name` property to ensure the serialization.

```
     "key":"MemberPreferences", //Easier debugging
     "name":"Member Preferences", //needed for serialization
     "id":"84CFE1C6-0345-461E-BF12-1BF346B8407C", //strongest relationship
```

Comment: Hello Kelly, I've discovered that this is actually incorrect. The behavior is as follows: If only `id` is used, then Event data **is not** serialized into the Data Extension. If only `name` is used, then Event data **is** serialized into the Data Extension. If both `id` and `name` is used, then Event data **is** serialized into the Data Extension. It appears that `name` is always required.

Comment: I guess you can't always trust what the developer says. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks Kelly, that was driving me nuts. I could not figure out why it was not updating. I even tried deleting everything and starting over. But `name` is definitely required here. Perhaps you can let the developer know this is the case, as I don't think `name` should be required.

Comment: I let them know - `name` seems like it's not the best requirement, and only `id` should work.  Sorry for the troubles - glad it's working.